# Reading from a word document using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I'm trying to read data from a docx file using java. The data is is tables. Is there a way to iterate through the table cells and extract the cell data?

Comment: Yes look at `docx4j` great library for doing this sort of thing...

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Write a library that can open, read, and manipulate Word documents, for some definitions of "open", "read", and "manipulate", and some definition of "Word document".
2. Find a third-party library that can do some or all of what is defined in (1).

Search "java docx library" in your favourite web search and see what comes up.

Answer (score -1):

This should help you.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleTable.java

The above was achieved using Apache POI

Here is the code from the link:

```
    package org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHeight;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTShd;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTString;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTrPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTVerticalJc;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STShd;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVerticalJc;

/**
 * This program creates a simple WordprocessingML table using POI XWPF API, and
 * a more complex, styled table using both XWPF and ooxml-schema. It's possible
 * that not all referenced wordprocessingml classes are defined in
 * poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta4. If this is the case, you'll need to use the full
 * ooxml-schemas.jar library.
 *
 * @author gisella bronzetti (original)
 * @author Gregg Morris (styled table)
 */
public class SimpleTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            createSimpleTable();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error trying to create simple table.");
            throw(e);
        }
        try {
            createStyledTable();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error trying to create styled table.");
            throw(e);
        }
    }

    public static void createSimpleTable() throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(3, 3);

        table.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("EXAMPLE OF TABLE");

        // table cells have a list of paragraphs; there is an initial
        // paragraph created when the cell is created. If you create a
        // paragraph in the document to put in the cell, it will also
        // appear in the document following the table, which is probably
        // not the desired result.
        XWPFParagraph p1 = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);

        XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
        r1.setBold(true);
        r1.setText("The quick brown fox");
        r1.setItalic(true);
        r1.setFontFamily("Courier");
        r1.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.DOT_DOT_DASH);
        r1.setTextPosition(100);

        table.getRow(2).getCell(2).setText("only text");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("simpleTable.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * Create a table with some row and column styling. I "manually" add the
     * style name to the table, but don't check to see if the style actually
     * exists in the document. Since I'm creating it from scratch, it obviously
     * won't exist. When opened in MS Word, the table style becomes "Normal".
     * I manually set alternating row colors. This could be done using Themes,
     * but that's left as an exercise for the reader. The cells in the last
     * column of the table have 10pt. "Courier" font.
     * I make no claims that this is the "right" way to do it, but it worked
     * for me. Given the scarcity of XWPF examples, I thought this may prove
     * instructive and give you ideas for your own solutions.

     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void createStyledTable() throws Exception {
        // Create a new document from scratch
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        // -- OR --
        // open an existing empty document with styles already defined
        //XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("base_document.docx"));

        // Create a new table with 6 rows and 3 columns
        int nRows = 6;
        int nCols = 3;
        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(nRows, nCols);

        // Set the table style. If the style is not defined, the table style
        // will become "Normal".
        CTTblPr tblPr = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr();
        CTString styleStr = tblPr.addNewTblStyle();
        styleStr.setVal("StyledTable");

        // Get a list of the rows in the table
        List<XWPFTableRow> rows = table.getRows();
        int rowCt = 0;
        int colCt = 0;
        for (XWPFTableRow row : rows) {
            // get table row properties (trPr)
            CTTrPr trPr = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            // set row height; units = twentieth of a point, 360 = 0.25"
            CTHeight ht = trPr.addNewTrHeight();
            ht.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(360));

            // get the cells in this row
            List<XWPFTableCell> cells = row.getTableCells();
            // add content to each cell
            for (XWPFTableCell cell : cells) {
                // get a table cell properties element (tcPr)
                CTTcPr tcpr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
                // set vertical alignment to "center"
                CTVerticalJc va = tcpr.addNewVAlign();
                va.setVal(STVerticalJc.CENTER);

                // create cell color element
                CTShd ctshd = tcpr.addNewShd();
                ctshd.setColor("auto");
                ctshd.setVal(STShd.CLEAR);
                if (rowCt == 0) {
                    // header row
                    ctshd.setFill("A7BFDE");
                }
                else if (rowCt % 2 == 0) {
                    // even row
                    ctshd.setFill("D3DFEE");
                }
                else {
                    // odd row
                    ctshd.setFill("EDF2F8");
                }

                // get 1st paragraph in cell's paragraph list
                XWPFParagraph para = cell.getParagraphs().get(0);
                // create a run to contain the content
                XWPFRun rh = para.createRun();
                // style cell as desired
                if (colCt == nCols - 1) {
                    // last column is 10pt Courier
                    rh.setFontSize(10);
                    rh.setFontFamily("Courier");
                }
                if (rowCt == 0) {
                    // header row
                    rh.setText("header row, col " + colCt);
                    rh.setBold(true);
                    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
                }
                else if (rowCt % 2 == 0) {
                    // even row
                    rh.setText("row " + rowCt + ", col " + colCt);
                    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
                }
                else {
                    // odd row
                    rh.setText("row " + rowCt + ", col " + colCt);
                    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
                }
                colCt++;
            } // for cell
            colCt = 0;
            rowCt++;
        } // for row

        // write the file
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("styledTable.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }

}
```